# Aggregator transformation -- Random Values for non aggregation fields

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario

> **ClientID** **SystemID** **EffectiveDate**
>
> 100        55     01/02/2015
>
> 100        50     01/02/2010
>
> 200        60     02/02/2015
>
> 200        65     02/02/2010

I need ClientID, SystemID, EffectiveDate for every client out there with the latest EffectiveDate, I did group by on ClientID, created a column with only output with Max(EffectiveDate), the issue is with SystemID, it is not returning the SystemID corresponding to the Max(EffectiveDate) rather some random SystemID, how do i get it to return the SystemID for that Max(EffectiveDate), to illustrate:

Required O/P:

> **ClientID**   **SystemID**   **EffectiveDate**
>
> 100                55               01/02/2015
>
> 200                60               02/02/2015

Actual O/P:

> **ClientID**   **SystemID**   **EffectiveDate**
>
> 100                50               01/02/2015
>
> 200                65             02/02/2015

Is this possible with Aggregator transformation? If not, please suggest any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregator by default passes the values for the last row of each group. So, you can simply put an sorter with ClientID and EffectiveDate as key (in that order) before the Aggregator transformation.

Also, select the Sorted Input option in the Aggregator. This will improve the Aggregator performance.